# Reformulation of BQP to SDP

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I run into the following reading some optimization papars:

$$\min_x x^TAx $$ where $x\in\{-1,1\}^n$ and $A\in S_n$,
Is equivalent to
$$ \min <X,A>$$
s.t $diag(X) = (1,1,...,1)\;\; rank(X) = 1$.
I guess $<.,.>$ is the Frobenius scalar product.
How can we see that those are the same?
Through the Lagrangian? 
Sorry for bad Latex I could not find anywhere how to write in optimization problems.

Comment: I don't get it, $x\in \{-1,1\}$? If that's the case, in order to $x^TAx$ be defined it's necessary that $A$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix. Is that the case?

And if it is, then $x^TAx=A$, for any $x\in \{-1,1\}$.

Comment: sorry for the typos, you understand now?

Comment: The commands for angle brackets are `\langle` and `\rangle`. For operator names that are not built into LaTeX, use `\operatorname{diag}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that in general $(A \in S_n)$

$$\min_x x^TAx = \min_x tr(x^TAx) = \min_x tr(Axx^T)=\min_X \langle A,X \rangle,$$ 
where $X=xx^T$ so obviously $rank(X)=1$. 
 Now the following sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ $\{x:x_i\in\{-1,1\}\},\{x:x^2_i=1\},\{x:\operatorname{diag}(xx^T)=1\}$ are equivalent so therefore the constraint $x\in\{-1,1\}^n$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{diag}(X) = (1,1,...,1)$. It follows that the problems are equivalent.