# Is there an alternative way to represent the $\operatorname{diag}$ function?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, computational-mathematics, article-writing

In optimization, it is common to see the so called $\operatorname{diag}$ function

Given a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\operatorname{diag}(x)$ =  $n \times n$ diagonal matrix with components of $x$ on the diagonal

For example:

[Optimization that involves inverse operation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726345/optimization-that-involves-inverse-operation)

[Reformulation of BQP to SDP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276308/reformulation-of-bqp-to-sdp)

The reason of using  $\operatorname{diag}$ is because it is used in several platforms such as MATLAB, and people generally understands what the function is supposed to do

> Is there a more linear algebra, step by step way of converting a
>   vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ into a diagonal matrix with components on
>   the diagonal without having a define a function that directly performs
>   the task ?

i.e. given $x$, we find a series of functions/steps $f_2 \circ f_1 (x)$ which give us the same matrix as  $\operatorname{diag}(x)$

Comment: What kind of functions are you looking for your $f_n$ to be? Because if $f_1 = \operatorname{diag}$, then you're done, but that's not what you're looking for. Are you looking for linear operators?

Comment: @GFauxPas I am thinking that through some matrix multiplication, we can extract all the component of a vector $x$, and then some how piece those components into a diagonal by introducing other matrices - basically just to find the representation of the diag operator

Comment: $\mathrm{diag}$ already is a linear operator.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear to me, but maybe you're looking for something along the following lines. For a fixed dimension $n$, the so-called matrix units $e_{ij}$ are $n \times n$ matrices given by a $1$ in the $ij$ place and $0$ entry everywhere else. Then given $x = (x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, the diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}(x) = x_{1}e_{11} + x_{2}e_{22} + \cdots + x_{n}e_{nn}$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim yes something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using tensor or Kronecker product notation, if $e_i = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots  \\ 1 \\  \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ and $e^i = (0, \dots, 1, \dots, 0)$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$ then we can represent $\operatorname{diag}(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ as

$$ \operatorname{diag}(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i (e^i \otimes e_i). $$

This is of course the same as writing

$$ \operatorname{diag}(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i e_{ii} $$

where $(e_ij)_{i,j=1}^n$ is the basis of $M_n(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ consisting of matrices $e_{ij}$ which have $1$ at the $i$-th row and $j$-th column and $0$ at all other places.

Comment: Wow great insight!

Answer (score 5):

There is a closed form.

$\mbox{diag}(x)=I_n\circ (xu)$ where $\circ$ is the Hadamard product, $I_n$ the identity matrix and $u=[1,\cdots,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\delta_{ijk}$ be the tensor such that

$$\delta_{ijk}=\begin{cases}1&\text{if}\;i=j=k\\
0&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

(in the particular basis you're working in).

Then

$$\mathrm{diag}(x)_{ij}=\sum_k\delta_{ijk}x_k$$

or in the summation convention just $\delta_{ijk}x_k$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $\operatorname{diag}$ is a linear operator, so you know there is some matrix that does what you're looking for.

Recall that to find a transformation matrix for a l.o. $T$ when working with the standard basis $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n$, we use the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}{T(e_1) \ \vert  \ \ T(e_2) \ \vert \ \ldots \ \vert \ T(e_n) }\end{bmatrix}$$

We can do the same thing here, though the matrix will have matrices as columns. Multiplying this by a vector on the right will result in a vector with one column, but that column will be a matrix.

I could go through an example, but the matrix won't be particularly interesting.

Note that this is the effectively the same answer as Alex_Wertheim's comment.